# Garbage collection and Strings

Tags: java

I have some doubts regarding Strings

Are they live on Heap or String pool?

And if on Heap then they will be garbage collected, if they are not reachable by any live thread.

And if on String pool then how they will be deleted or removed because as we know Garbage Collection happens only on heap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String s = new String("abc");
```

the string object referred by s will be on heap and the string literal "abc" will be in string pool. The objects in the string pool will not be garbage collected. They are there to be reused during the lifetime of the program, to improve the performance.

Comment: If you are referring to the _constant pool_ which is part of the class definition, then you _can_ unload the constant pool, provided you can unload the class (which normally requires dereferencing the class loader and all references to it's loaded classes).  More difficult than your typical program, but Tomcat does it.

Answer (score 5):

They are all *stored* in the heap, but `intern()`ed strings (including string literals in the source) are *referenced* from a pool in the `String` class.

If they appear as literals in the source code, including constant string expressions (e.g. `"a" + "b"`) then they will also be referenced from the `Class` the appear in, which usually means they will last as long as the process runs.

**Edit**:
When you call `intern()` on a string in your code it is also added to this pool, but because it uses weak references the string *can* still be garbage collected if it is no longer in use.

See also:
[interned Strings : Java Glossary](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/interned.html)

Quote from that article:

> The collection of Strings registered in this HashMap is sometimes called the String pool. However, they are ordinary Objects and live on the heap just like any other (perhaps in an optimised way since interned Strings tend to be long lived).

Answer (score 1):

String **Alex** goes into the literal pool, stays there as long as the process runs (or the web application remains loaded.) as told by **finnw** and is never garbage collected. String name2 doesn't allocate memory for "Alex" and reuses it from the literal pool.

PS: Literal pool is on the heap as well.

For string **John** two objects are created with reference name3 and name4 which are garbage collectible.

```
String name = "Alex";
String name2 = "Alex";

String name3 = new String("John");
String name4 = new String("John");
```