# String object in pool

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Garbage collection and Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2202162/garbage-collection-and-strings)

Will the String literal object placed in String pool area ever be eligible for garbage collection?