# How to use less memory when assign big new String

Tags: java, string, memory

Java String is immutable so

when you create a string, a block of memory is assigned for it in the heap, and when you change its value, a new block of memory is created for that string, and the old one becomes eligible for garbage collection, for example

```
String str = func1_return_big_string_1()"; //not literal
String str= func2_return_big_string_2()"; //not literal
```

But as garbage collection takes time to kick in so we are practically have memory in heap containing both big string 1 & 2. They can be a issue for me if this happens a lot.

Is there a way to make big string 2 to use the same location in memory of string 1 so we don't need have extra space when we assign big string 2 to str.

Edit:
Thanks for all the input and in the end I realized I shouldn't expecting java code to behave like c++ code(i.e, different memory footprint). I have wrote a c++ 11 demo which works as expected, biggest memory footprint is around 20M (biggest file I was trying to load) with rvalue reference and move assignment operator all kick in as expected.
Below demo done in VS2012 with c++ 11.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

string readFile(const string &fileName)
{
    ifstream ifs(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

    ifstream::pos_type fileSize = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    vector<char> bytes(fileSize);
    ifs.read(&bytes[0], fileSize);

    return string(&bytes[0], fileSize);
}

class test{
public:
    string m_content;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string base("c:\\data");
    string ext(".bin");
    string filename;
    test t;
    //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
    cout << "about to start" << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<=50; ++i) {
        cout << i << endl;
        filename = base + std::to_string(i) + ext;
        //rvalue reference & move assignment operator here
        //so no unnecessary copy at all
        t.m_content = readFile(filename);
        cout << "szie of content" << t.m_content.length() << endl;
    }
    cout << "end" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: These aren't string *literals* we're talking about, right? Presumably the big strings are returned from some method, correct?

Comment: Use a Char array instead?   
Looking through the API, I only see String.replace() as a likely candidate, but that requires you to use Regex on it, and I dont know how the memory allocation works for that

Comment: @arshajii: yes thats right

Comment: Secondly, have you done any tests to determine that there is really a memory issue here? The GC should be pretty efficient when it comes to this.

Comment: No but I can foreseeen this could happen, at least I don't want to reply on GC if I don't have to.

Comment: How big are the strings? Are we talking thousands, millions, or billions of characters here?

Comment: +1 @arshajii. Unless you're doing a _lot_ of work, the GC is smarter than you, and if you _are_ doing a lot of work, you should be using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Can StringBuilder been use to assign , I don't need appending ?

Comment: @Gob00st: Depends what you mean by "assign," but probably. Have you read its docs?

Comment: @LouisWasserman: its typically use a lot append() which is not I want.

Comment: @Gob00st: _How_ do you want to modify the string?  If you just want to replace the value of the first string, trust that the GC is smarter and faster than anything you could do.

Comment: @Gob00st: Take a look at my answer. Everybody downvotes, but it is the only correct answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid having both the old and new String at the same time in memory, you can explicitly allow the GC to clean it up by assigning `null` to the variable:

```
String str;
str = func1_return_big_string_1();
str = null; // Now, GC can clean, when it needs extra memory for the String.
str = func2_return_big_string_2();
```

**UPDATE:** To support my claim, I wrote a test case that proves I'm right: http://ideone.com/BwGfSN.
The code demonstrates the difference between (using the Finalizer):

```
GCTest test;
// Without the null assignment
test = create(0);
test = create(1);
test = null;
System.gc();

try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch (Exception e){}
System.out.println();

// With the null assignment
test = create(2);
test = null;
test = create(3);
test = null;
System.gc();
```

Comment: Yes, you can. By calling `System.gc()`. But that is not what I'm showing here. The idea is to release the previous String object, in order to allow the GC to kick in while creating the string within `func2`.

Comment: Funny to see how everybody is downvoting, while this is really the technical answer to his problem.

Comment: May be they downvote because JVM should do this `null` assignment for user? JIT can understand that `str` is not referenced anymore in the current evaluation scope and can be GC-freed.

Comment: @AndreyChaschev: No, that is not true. While in the `func2_return_big_string_2()` method, the reference to the other big string (stored in `str`) still exists. Only when the method returns, the value of `str` is overwritten. So, while creating the next big string, the GC can't free the previous one. Therefor, assigning it to `null` allows the GC to get rid of it, when `func2_return_big_string_2()` is allocating the next one.

Comment: There is also a JIT which can optimize the code so it looks as it is stated in your answer. It's a correct optimization. I've re-read the original question and, yes, it's mistakenly stated that two string would be on heap. My guess is that there will be only one after the JIT optimization, it really kicks it and code sample is quite trivial. What it can not optimize however is memory allocation needed in each of the methods.

Comment: The JIT does this optimization NOT. At least not my JVM. Carefully look at this code: http://ideone.com/BwGfSN.

Comment: In this case it really does not. Even after I added `final`s and put it into the loop. And this is really hard to explain. Anyway, this is something new for me, upvoting :-)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: I have try nulling the String without calling System.gc() and it did help I guess GC kicked in for the null string ? Shouldn't GC kick in even without the explicitly nulling the String as it's no longer referenced ?

Comment: @Gob00st: You are right. The GC will kick in without calling System.gc(). This is because he will detect the JVM is running out of memory. The difference is that GC cannot clean up the old String as long as the second method is running, because while the second method is running, the reference to the old String still exists. Only when the method returns and overwrites the str reference, the old String is not longer referenced. So, if you nullify the reference before entering the second method, GC can free the memory of the old String while the second method is building the next big String.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: this one so far seems saved the most memory. But even with all the nulling and System.gc(), it still doesn't seems to get rid of all the null (none referenced string). So basically instead of having around 20M memory usage steady (if I write this in c++ 11), it spikes up to 600M then reduced to around 180M with your method (without any extra copy, it should be max 20M for my java test app). I guess this is Java not c++, bumpy ride instead of smooth one :)

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: I guess, in general, you are be right, but note that the JIT doesn't ever get invoked in your test case. It only kicks in if there's some significant time spent in the code. I could imagine that it could eliminate your null asignment. See a [related question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547284/can-jit-do-this-field-access-optimization).

Comment: @maaartinus: I think you simply don't really know what JIT is (was). JIT is the compiler that compiles the bytecode into native machinecode. It is not "the optimizer". It can do optimizations, because it's the compiler.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Could we agree that JIT is the *optimizing compiler*? Could we also agree that JVM can run without it? If not, please take a look [here](http://www.herongyang.com/JVM/Micro-Benchmark-Interpreted-Only-Mode.html). The first few iterations are always interpreted, agreed?

Comment: To settle this old case, @maaartinus is right. This can be demonstrated by raising the `sleep` times in this program and then running it with `-Xcomp`. Eliminating variables with are not read, is one of the the JIT’s simplest tricks. But a method running a single time, like this `main` method usually doesn’t get optimized and even if, switching an already running method to a compiled version has significant restrictions. See also [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24380219/2711488)

Answer (score 2):

Use StringBuffer, StringBuffer.append()

Comment: I think he wants to completely reassign `str` to a new string, not somehow mutate a preexisting one.

Comment: Is it possible in Java? Java's Strings are immutable. The only option to make them mutable is to use (like @Praveen suggested) StringBuffer or StringBuilder class.

Answer (score 2):

I see several options:

1. Use `char[]`.
2. Copy `StringBuilder` into your version `MyStringBuilder` with a public reusable buffer. The major disadvantage is that it lacks regexes. That's what I did when I needed to boost performance.
3. Hack for JDK <=6: there is a protected constructor to reuse strings/wrap char buffers. It's not there anymore for JDK 7+. One needs to be really cautious with this, and it's not a problem once you have C/C++ background.
4. Copy `String` into the `MutableString` with a public reusable buffer. I don't think there would a problem adding your custom regex matcher as there are a plenty of them available.

Comment: I don't need to worry about regexes for this particular case, so could you give a example of your 2> solution?

Comment: Here is a [sample](https://github.com/chaschev/chutils/blob/22be4d0d1a872733b115c7d5995c552a3a6ca9f4/src/main/java/chaschev/lang/OpenStringBuilder.java). `reset()` method was added and a few others to reuse the `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't really matter for non-interned Strings.  If you start running out of memory, the garbage collector will remove any objects that are no longer referenced.

Interned Strings are much harder to collect, see [Garbage collection of String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324143/garbage-collection-of-string-literals) for details

**EDIT** A non-interned String is just like a normal object.  Once there are no more references to it, it will get garbage collected.

if `str` is the only reference left pointing to the original String and `str` is changed to point to something else, then the original String is eligible for garbage collection.  So you no longer have to worry about running out of memory because the JVM will collect it if memory is required.

Comment: @Gob00st then my second sentence is my answer

Comment: I am not sure I get your answer, do you care to explain more? also edited my question.

Comment: @Yes without reference GC will collect eventually I was hoping it can does the job quickly so the memory doesn't have to spike up.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found a [MutableString](http://dsiutils.di.unimi.it/docs/it/unimi/dsi/lang/MutableString.html) implementation. It is available in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cit.unimi.dsi%7Cdsiutils%7C2.1.3%7Cjar). Here is an extract from their JavaDoc page:

> - Mutable strings occupy little space— their only attributes are a backing character array and an integer;
> - their methods try to be as efficient as possible: for instance, if some limitation on a parameter is implied by limitation on array access, we do not check it explicitly, and Bloom filters are used to speed up multi-character substitutions;
> - they let you access directly the backing array (at your own risk);
> - they implement `CharSequence,` so, for instance, you can match or split a mutable string against a regular expression using the standard Java API;
> - they implement `Appendable`, so they can be used with `Formatter` and similar classes;

**UPDATE**

You can utilize `Appendable` interface of this `MutableString` to read a file with almost zero-memory overhead (8KB, which is the default buffer size in Java). With Guava's [CharStreams.copy](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/CharStreams.html#copy%28com.google.common.io.InputSupplier,%20java.lang.Appendable%29) it looks like this:

```
MutableString str = new MutableString((int) file.length());
CharStreams.copy(Files.newReaderSupplier(file, Charset.defaultCharset()), str);
System.out.println(str);
```

[Full working example](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7106875).

Comment: Great! Accepting an answer motivates our future contributions! :-)

Comment: Though it's not saving much because when the mutable string does the append, it's copying the char array loaded from file into it's own array. I was hoping it can do move semantic with rvalue reference in c++ 11: meaning pointing it's array point to the temp object's array(loaded from file), but its not doing the smart thing... Anything upvote for you. Cheers

Comment: I've updated an answer with an example of buffered reading into this `MutableString`. HTH

Comment: The code won't compile: The generic method copy(InputSupplier<R>, OutputSupplier<W>) of type CharStreams is not applicable for the arguments (InputSupplier<FileInputStream>, MutableString). The inferred type FileInputStream is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <R extends Readable & Closeable>

Comment: My bad, this one is for memory buffers. I've updated & tested it for files. [Also available as Gist](https://gist.github.com/chaschev/7106875).

Comment: For a lot of use cases, the built-in [`CharBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap(char%5B%5D,int,int)) will be sufficient. It can wrap a `char[]` array and implements `Appendable`, `CharSequence`, `Readable`, and in recent versions even `Comparable<CharBuffer>`. But mutable data structures are not always the most efficient solution. In the best case, [`Files.readString(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)) works without any intermediate buffers.