# Can JIT do this field access optimization?

Tags: java, optimization, garbage-collection, jit

*Disclaimer: Please no advice concerning premature optimization. I'm just curious.*

Imagine I want to make sure that some objects referenced by a field can be garbage collected ASAP. I'm using a home-made singly linked list like this

```
class BigData {
    byte[] someBigArray;
    BigData next;
}

private BigData bigData;
```

and iterate like this

```
while (bigData != null) {
    process(bigData);
    bigData = bigData.next;
}
```

Is the JIT free to change it like follows?

```
BigData tmp = bigData;
while (tmp != null) {
    process(tmp);
    tmp = tmp.next;
}
bigData = null;
```

Assume there's no other reference to any instance of `BigData`. Assume `process` is a simple inlineable method not accessing the field `bigData`. Both snippets are equivalent (assuming no exception gets thrown in between), the only difference is that the second moves the field access from the loop to the outside.

*Disclaimer repeated: Please no advice concerning premature optimization. I'm just curious.*

---

To answer the comment *"Even if the change you 'want' is what the JIT does, why would that make the GC collect them faster/sooner?"*: If the JIT does the change, then that all the big objects can be only collected after the loop. If it doesn't, then each time the loop advances one more object becomes eligible for GC.

#### Addendum:

Actually, whenever the JIT is free to do the above transform, it can do this one instead:

```
BigData tmp = bigData;
bigData = null;
while (tmp != null) {
    process(tmp);
    tmp = tmp.next;
}
```

I can't see any disadvantage here and it makes all objects collectible as soon as in the original code.

Comment: Even if the change you 'want' is what the JIT does, why would that make the GC collect them faster/sooner?

Comment: And how would knowing the answer to this possibly change the way you write code?  It could be different in different versions of the JIT compiler or the JVM.  Also, `bigData` had to be assigned from some other reference, so that reference must still exist.

Comment: It is a common manual optimization technique to use local variables like `tmp` here to save on field accesses, so my guess is that JIT doesn't do that by itself.

Comment: @CyrilleKa Also, that people do it manually does *not* mean the JIT compiler doesn't optimize it - it could also mean people underestimate optimizers, which is rather common in my experience.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: *"And how would knowing the answer to this possibly change the way you write code?"* Not at all. I'm just curious. *"It could be different in different versions of the JIT compiler or the JVM."* Assuming the JIT is allowed to do this. And that's my very question. *"Also, bigData had to be assigned from some other reference, so that reference must still exist."* No.

Comment: @delnan Sure, but well, it is something that profilers say is working substantially; I saw it in the JDK API implementation itself (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841894/why-assign-a-final-field-variable-to-a-local-copy-before-calling-its-method-bes) and I think I saw it in Guava too, so knowledgeable people apparently think JIT won't do it too.

Comment: @CyrilleKa Congratulations, you just found an answer. Now post it as answer (elaborate a bit, a link on its own doesn't make a good answer) and reap that sweet reputation :-)

Comment: @Cyrille Ka: Caching a field into a local variable makes the *bytecode* smaller. Accessing a field take at least four bytes (`aload_0` `getfield` <two byte index>) while accessing a local variable takes at most two bytes. Accessing the local variable might be faster as long as the optimizer didn’t take any action. But once the optimizer did its work, it makes no difference anymore (unless the field is `volatile`)

Comment: @Holger: I don't think that the two bytes saved are worth it. I guess the reason is faster code before the optimizer kicks in. Maybe only C2 does this optimization, maybe they did it with some weaker optimizers in mind (e.g. Dalvik?).

Comment: @maaartinus: It might be a bit of both, saving bytecode *and* some CPU cycles for non-hotspots. But I remember seeing JRE source code where a comment explicitly said something like “storing into a local variable to save some bytecode instructions”. But it is for sure that the optimizer does reducing memory access as well as reordering, otherwise we never needed to care about memory consistency effects when doing multi-threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the optimizer *can* optimize

```
while (bigData != null) {
    process(bigData);
    bigData = bigData.next;
}
```

into

```
BigData tmp = bigData;
while (tmp != null) {
    process(tmp);
    tmp = tmp.next;
}
bigData = null;
```

if the `bigData` field is not `volatile` and the `process` method has no side-effects that forbid this optimization.

But in practice, the code transformation, if any, will look completely different. It’s typical that optimizers do loop unrolling, creating a code block performing a certain number of iterations and do the field storage operation before taking a backwards jump. So there are certain “savepoints” where the garbage collector can jump in. But if the `process` method contains code that accesses the `bigData` field or might allocate memory, etc, the field storage will be performed before every invocation.

Comment: I would suggest you to stress what question is not about JIT optimization, but about Java Memory Model which specify what JIT is allowed to do.

Comment: AFAIK, only way for JIT to know about process() side effects is to inline it. Unless process() is inlined JIT will always store changes to bigData field before calling process().

Comment: @Alexey Ragozin: the memory model specifies the restrictions for the JIT regarding side-effects visible to other threads. There is the obvious additional constraint that the code must retain its semantics regarding the one thread executing it. Of course, for the JIT to know about possible side-effects the `process` method must be either inlined or non-polymorph. E.g. the JIT might prove for a `static` or `private` method that is has no side-effects and remember this so when encountering a loop invoking this method the JIT knows enough without having to inline it.