# How to stop two arrays having the same memory

Tags: java

I have two identical 2D array's of characters however I want to make it so that when I make changes to one it doesn't effect the other. I am assuming it is because they are sharing the same space in memory and was wondering how to stop this.

```
private char[][] a;
private char[][] b;

a = new char[8][];
b = new char[8][];

while(file.hasNext()) //reads 8 lines from a file and adds it to text to both arrays
{
    char[] constant =  file.nextLine().toCharArray();
    a[i] = constant;
    b[i] = constant;
    i++;
}
```

then if i were to run the code

```
a[0][0] = 't';
```

then it also changes b[0][0] to 't'

Comment: Post your code. Variables dont' share memory in Java.

Comment: @EJP _Technically_, they might be stored in the same index of a variable table. (busting balls)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That would implicitly violate both the Java Language Specification #4.5 and the Java Virtual Machine Specification #2.5 (same wording in each).

Comment: @EJP JLS Chapter 4.5 is about parameterized types. Can you check again? Or clarify.

Comment: @EJP Maybe I should specify _local_ variables. See [chapter 2.6 of JVM Spec.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/jvms7.pdf). Also, take a look at [this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437699/outofmemoryerror-when-seemingly-unrelated-code-block-commented-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea was:

```
char[] orig = // something;
char[] copy = orig.clone();
```

But be aware:
clone() only creates a shallow copy of an array. That means for a 2D-Array with chars you have to clone each subarray.

For further information about clone() click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29).

Your code should look something like this

```
char[][] original = new char[3][3];
char[][] copy = new char[orignal.length][0];

for(int i = 0; i < original.length; i++){
    copy[i] = original[i].clone();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are objects. When you assign them like this

```
int[][] firstArray = getArray();  // Get your array from somewhere
int[][] secondArray = firstArray; // Assign an array
```

you have only one array, but you have a second *variable* that references it. Essentially, `secondArray[i][j]` and `firstArray[i][j]` refer to the same object in memory by two different names.

To fix this, make a copy of the array. A simple way of doing it is to call the `clone()` method on the original array, like this:

```
int[][] secondArray = new int[firstArray.length][];
for (int i = 0 ; i != secondArray.length ; i++) {
    secondArray[i] = (int[])firstArray[i].clone();
}
```

Note: `clone()` creates a shallow copy. If you

Comment: Be aware that clone() creates a shallow copy of the object. In your example it seems that clone() creates a deep copy.

Comment: I have just found out that this doesn't work with an array that has more then two dimensions. However if you loop it for each nested array it works

Comment: @icantdojavabuticandovb Correct - you can `clone()` only the last dimension; you need loops for all the remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two identical 2D array's of characters however I want to make it so that when I make changes to one it doesn't effect the other. I am assuming it is because they are sharing the same space in memory and was wondering how to stop this.

Arrays don't share memory. Nor do any other variables in Java.

Ergo if changes to one affect the other, you *don't* have two arrays at all. You only have one, with two references to it. Updating the array via one reference is visible via the other reference.

The solution is therefore to *create* two arrays, not just one.