# Java 10: Byte Code Generation for Enhanced For Loops

Tags: java, javac

The following example describes the generation of the following lines of code until Java 9.

```
List data = new ArrayList<>();for (String b : data); 

public class Test

{
  public Test() {}
  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString) throws IOException {
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();
    String str;
    for (Iterator localIterator = localArrayList.iterator(); localIterator.hasNext(); str = (String)localIterator.next()) {}
}
```

In Java 10, iterator variables are declared outside for loops and initialized to the null value immediately once the operation is over, so GC can get rid of unused memory.

```
{
    Iterator iterator = data.iterator();
    for (; iterator.hasNext();) 
    {
        String b = (String)iterator.next();
    }
    b = null;
    iterator = null;
}
```

How is setting reference null explicitly better than reference going out of scope by the end of the for loop.

Source: https://dzone.com/articles/features-in-java-10

Also, adding link from the comments : https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8192858

Comment: Where is the bytecode here?

Comment: You say "In Java 10" in both sections, presumably you mean "In Java <10" in one section. Also, this is obviosuly decomblied bytecode - how do you know it's not just your decompiler?

Comment: "In Java 10, iterator variables are declared outside for loops and initialized to the null value immediately once the operation is over" - says who? Please provide a reference for this information. Better yet, point out where it is specified in the JLS section on enhanced for-loops: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Comment: I found this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8192858

Comment: Source is: https://dzone.com/articles/features-in-java-10. Now I am wondering about the authenticity.

Comment: @d.j.brown good find. that's a pretty ugly inconsistent hack, it seems. what makes enhanced for loops such a special case that it should be treated differently from any local variable going out of scope, like variables declared in a normal for-loop, block-local variables, etc. For people who program small, single-responsibility methods (like one should), this is only going to reduce performance (although slightly only).

Comment: @RoshiniSingh This one has better explanation: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175883

Comment: Thanks @d.j.brown

Comment: @d.j.brown thanks I edited. let me know if it looks fine.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Thanks for pointing to better explanation

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt the good thing about it is that this “pretty ugly inconsistent hack” [is not a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64232267/compiled-code-in-java-8-vs-compiled-code-in-java-11/64235735#comment113595566_64235735). I’d say, the fact that no-one has noticed yet, demonstrates how “important” this fix is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: There already exists a related question: [Java "for" statement implementation prevents garbage collecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403347/java-for-statement-implementation-prevents-garbage-collecting) that provides more information.

After reading through the bug-reports (https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8192858 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8175883) the reason for this change can be summarised as the following:

There was an issue in the bytecode produced by javac which resulted in a reference to an array / iterable being kept after the completion of the loop.

As a result, even if an array / iterable is explicitly nullified, there is still a reference to the array / iterable which means that the array / iterable was not eligible for garbage collection until leaving the scope of the method.

With large arrays / iterables (as per the example below) this could result in an `OutOfMemoryError`.

This is demonstrated by this use case here (taken from the bug report):

```
public class IteratorInOneScope { 

    private static final int HALF_OF_MEMORY = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() * 0.5); 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        byte[] data = new byte[HALF_OF_MEMORY]; 

        for (byte b : data); // <-- if you comment this line - the application finished successfully 
        data = null; // this expects to discard reference -> allow to release the memory 

        byte[] data2 = new byte[HALF_OF_MEMORY]; // the memory can't be allocated second time, if the "for" loop statement above is used 

        System.out.println("Success"); 
    } 
}
```

Which compiled to the following bytecode:

```
 0: getstatic #2 // Field HALF_OF_MEMORY:I 
 3: newarray byte 
 5: astore_0 <==== array ref in slot #0 

 6: aload_0 
 7: astore_1 <==== array ref in slot #1 

 8: aload_1 
 9: arraylength 
10: istore_2 

11: iconst_0 
12: istore_3 

13: iload_3 
14: iload_2 
15: if_icmpge 29 

18: aload_1 
19: iload_3 
20: baload 
21: istore 4 
23: iinc 3, 1 
26: goto 13 

29: aconst_null 
30: astore_0 <== nulls slot #0 

31: getstatic #2 // Field HALF_OF_MEMORY:I 
34: newarray byte 
36: astore_1 
37: getstatic #3 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream; 
40: ldc #4 // String Success 
42: invokevirtual #5 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V 
45: return
```

There is no update to [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), for this reason:

> JLS 14.14.2 is only concerned with semantics of the statement, not
>   garbage collection behavior. Compilers are free to generate whatever
>   bytecode they want that produces the specified behavior. So, if javac
>   wants to set some unused locals to null, it's free to do so. No spec
>   change necessary, and it would be a mistake to include it in the spec,
>   because it doesn't impact the statement's semantics.