# Is there any good examples of jvm reuse LocalVariableTable slot?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot, decompiler

I'm learning Java's bytecode by read the [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se15/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13)

I'm confused about the LocalVariableTable attribute, which official document says when executing a .class file, all slots of LocalVariableTable may be reused.

I cannot write any code compiled like this:

```java
sipush xxx
istore_0
.....
dup
astore_0
```

Can anyone give me some examples?

Comment: Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403347/java-for-statement-implementation-prevents-garbage-collecting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437699/outofmemoryerror-when-seemingly-unrelated-code-block-commented-out

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thank you, you save lot lot lot my days

Comment: @neocanable, here's the latest documentation, _https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no “java's assembly language” so you can not compile a pseudo assembly code with the tools provided by the JDK. You can only use the other direction, print the bytecode of a compiled class with `javap`.

There are 3rd party tools providing an assembly language for the JVM, e.g. Krakatau, but neither is part of a standard. Most of those languages will look similar or even offer compatibility with other tools though, as they use the same mnemonics from the JVM specification and the output format of `javap` as a starting point.

Reusing variable slots is a trivial thing. It happens all the time when local variables have disjunct scopes. E.g.

```java
import java.util.spi.ToolProvider;

public class ReusedVariableSlots {
    static class Example {
      public static void exampleMethod() {
          { short s = 1234; }
          { Object o = null; }
      }
      private Example() {}
  }
  public static void main(String... arg) {
      ToolProvider.findFirst("javap").ifPresentOrElse(
          javap ->javap.run(System.out, System.err, "-c", Example.class.getName()),
          () -> System.out.println("javap not found"));
  }
}
```

will print something like

```
Compiled from "ReusedVariableSlots.java"
class ReusedVariableSlots$Example {
  public static void exampleMethod();
    Code:
       0: sipush        1234
       3: istore_0
       4: aconst_null
       5: astore_0
       6: return
}
```

[online demo on tio.run](https://tio.run/##bZBNboMwEIX3nGLECiQYqT871O7SXZpI7QUcbIipsS17jFpFOTs1gSik6iyskd/TzPemYwMrO/41jrK3xhF08QMDSYXeSvw0Ru2dGSQXrkqSWjHvYcukhlMCsTwxkjXM/5tv1lslFmkqGw4qyotrMJKDmE1bQUfDs3xlnuoE/jhReHiBh8en5wrOf/TdoRM1gYkGHZRaG26ddXJgJK5E05pZnN9/sPqYKfsgJ3WLiMBcu0ZbnwEbqfmbdJ6ydDqWTXOUzd4JLzTt3EZ5kd0xX0xQvs4NuhAX/XgSPZpABSy9cK6AtKzT4kqNl6tiK@id9TFDXtyNjaHizNskjKE1Kb1QgTYEjQmap3leLeHPyTj@Ag)

Comment: { short s = 1234; }  { Object o = null; } does it mean that different scopes will be reused? thank you for you answer

Comment: The slot will be reused; as you can see, both variables use the index zero. That’s compiler specific, but all relevant compilers do it that way. Note that `{ int a = 0; } int b = 1;` and `int a = 0; a = 1;` produce exactly the same bytecode (with common compilers). To the bytecode, it doesn’t matter whether the source code has one or two variables.

Comment: @Holger I believe you should know about asmtools and their jasm/jdis commands: https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/CodeTools/asmtools Being a project under OpenJDK it can be considered as a "standard".

Comment: @user882813 a tool is not a standard at all. Specifications make a standard. And being hosted under OpenJDK doesn’t give a tool a special significance.

Comment: @Holger Well, it is not a standard de jure and not standartized neither by JLS nor JVMS. However, it is developed by and used by JVM developers for JVM development purposes.

Thus it can be viewed as a standard de facto. At least it is more preferable than Krakatau, Jasmine or any other third-party JVM-targeted bytecode assemblers.