# How == Operator works in Java

Tags: java

I was reading about [== operator in java](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/) and found that it used to compare memory reference the below example is from given link.

> ```
> String obj1 = new String("xyz");
>
> // now obj2 and obj1 reference the same place in memory
> String obj2 = obj1;
>
> if(obj1 == obj2)
>    System.out.printlln("obj1==obj2 is TRUE");
> else
>   System.out.println("obj1==obj2 is FALSE");
> ```
>
> Note in the code above that obj2 and obj1 both reference the same
>   place in memory because of this line: “String obj2 = obj1;”. And
>   because the “==” compares the memory reference for each object, it
>   will return true. And, the output of the code above will be:

After that I write code randomly to check == operator but why it returning true in this example?

```
String obj1 = "ABC";
String obj2 = "ABC";
if(obj1 == obj2)
System.out.println("obj1==obj2 is TRUE");
else
System.out.println("obj1==obj2 is FALSE");
```

Does "ABC" string saved in the one memory place then obj1 and obj2 sharing that memory reference?

Even int also returning true.

```
int obj1=3;
int obj2=3;
```

Comment: Some reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251650/how-java-string-immutable

Comment: when you use double quotes to create string instead of new operator it first looks string pool and if it finds string with same string  returns referance to it otherwise creates new one

Comment: @Murinik why mark as duplicate? even my question is different I edit it.

Comment: @EthicalThinker the answer and explanation is the same - marking as duplicate means people who ask questions that are semantically the same will be directed to an established answer pool.

Comment: Haven't you ever read a book about Java and learned the difference between reference types and primitive types?

Comment: @Tom I know about primitive types and reference types.

Comment: @Tom Nice man, Understood, the == and equals() will make different for References type?

Comment: *"the == and equals() will make different for References type?"* -> *"I was reading about == operator in java and found that it used to compare memory reference"* ... what do you think?

Comment: @Tom I mean, equals for Objects not for int. 2nd compare memory reference mean, == used to compare if objects refers same memory place where literal stored. But I need to search why java used equals instead == also for objects.

Comment: *"But I need to search why java used equals instead == also for objects."* Maybe because the language designers thought: why should `==` behave differently depending on the variable type?

Comment: @Tom it should not and also not behaving differently, But I read that `==` perform _reference equality_. and I'm sure it comparing reference not exact value.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't not behave differently, so are you still confused about *"But I need to search why java used equals instead == also for objects."*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are a bit special as they use [String interning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10579062/1076463).
So yes, behind the screens those two strings have the same memory reference (but do not count on it for string comparison. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1076463)).

Replace your strings by

```
Object obj1 = new Object();
Object obj2 = new Object();
```

and you will get the expected output.

Comment: ok, this for just String? `int obj1=3;
        int obj2=3;` this also printing true

Comment: @EthicalThinker That's because those aren't objects, but plain memory values ;-)

Comment: @watery it's mean java will share each memory that repeats even, string int, double long and any other type without new keyword?

Comment: @NewBie Of course not! I mean, it's not that simple. Primitive types are treated differently than objects; e.g. when you pass an `int` to a method, the latter gets a *copy* of the value, whereas if you pass an object, the method receives a *reference* to it. But then, I think (I'm unsure though) that `Integer`s (and the others), being immutable, are held in some kind of cache.

Comment: @watery why java introduce equals() method == is not enough also for objects?

Comment: @NewBie This is a questions & answers site: if you have more questions do a search, and if you're not satisfied then post a new question :-)