# Can java string literals be garbage collected?. If Yes, how to prove it?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, classloader

Can java *String literals* like `"abc"` be garbage collected?. If yes, how can we *programatially* prove that they are GCed?

Comment: schizophrenia? :) just kidding, good one :)

Comment: @zubergu - Not really.. Just had some free time.. Thought of using it *judiciously* :)

Comment: let me look up judiciously... :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbage collection of String literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324143/garbage-collection-of-string-literals)

Comment: @weston - I have seen that question. I wanted to code / see it myself.. :)

Comment: @weston - That question doesn't contain code to prove what is happening.. So, this isn't a dup

Answer (score 6):

Yes, post Java7,  String literals can be garbage collected if the class loader which loaded it gets garbage collected and there are no references to the string literal.

Note : In Java -8, you will have to call GC twice in order to ensure that ClassLoaders get GCed (Metaspace.. pfff..Using a different GC won't help).

```
Case -1 : 
//ClassLoaders don't get GCed.

Code :
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// main class
 class TestStringLiteralGC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> c1 = new CustomClassLoader().loadClass("Test"); // load class once
        Class<?> c2 = new CustomClassLoader().loadClass("Test");  // load class again
        System.out.println("c1 : " + c1); // c1 : class Test
        System.out.println("c2 : " + c2); // c2 : class Test 
        System.out.println("c1 == c2 :" + (c1 == c2)); //c1 == c2 :false --> So, now we have 2 different class objects for same class.
        Field f1 = c1.getDeclaredField("s"); // getting field s of c1
        f1.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of c1.s :"+ System.identityHashCode(f1.get(null))); // Identity hashCode of c1.s :1442407170
        Field f2 = c2.getDeclaredField("s");  // getting field s of c2
        f2.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of c2.s :"+ System.identityHashCode(f2.get(null))); // Identity hashCode of c2.s :1442407170
        System.out.println("c1.s == c2.s : " + (f1.get(null) == f2.get(null))); // c1.s == c2.s : true ==> c1.s is the same "instance" as c2.s
        //Don't make c1 and c2 eligible for GC
        // So, now, there are still references to "abc"
//      f1 = null;
//      c1 = null;
//      f2 = null;
//      c2 = null;
       //call GC explicitly. Yes, twice.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // use the same string literal in main. Just to test that the same literal is being used.
        String s = "abc";
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : " + System.identityHashCode(s)); // Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : 1442407170 ==> Yes. The IDHashcodes are the same
    }

}
// Our class which will be loaded
class Test {
    static String s = "abc"; // Our little hero!.The string literal. 
}
//Our custom ClassLoader to load the class "Test"
class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    // finalize() is to check if Object is unreachable (and ready for GC)
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("CustomClassLoader finalize called.." + this);
    };

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (!name.equals("Test")) {
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }
        try {
            InputStream in = ClassLoader
                    .getSystemResourceAsStream("Test.class");
            byte[] a = new byte[10000];
            int len = in.read(a);
            in.close();
            return defineClass(name, a, 0, len);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}

O/P :
// NO GC of Classloaders :(
c1 : class Test
c2 : class Test
c1 == c2 :false
Identity hashCode of c1.s :1442407170  // Value- 1
Identity hashCode of c2.s :1442407170  // Value -2
c1.s == c2.s : true
Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : 1442407170 // Value -3
```

> Same IdentityHashCode for (1,2) and 3 means the same string literal
>   "abc" is being used in all 3 places.

```
Case : 2 
//Force GC of ClassLoaders and check again.

Code :
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

// main class
 class TestStringLiteralGC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class<?> c1 = new CustomClassLoader().loadClass("Test"); // load class once
        Class<?> c2 = new CustomClassLoader().loadClass("Test");  // load class again
        System.out.println("c1 : " + c1); // c1 : class Test
        System.out.println("c2 : " + c2); // c2 : class Test 
        System.out.println("c1 == c2 :" + (c1 == c2)); //c1 == c2 :false --> So, now we have 2 different class objects for same class.
        Field f1 = c1.getDeclaredField("s"); // getting field s of c1
        f1.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of c1.s :"+ System.identityHashCode(f1.get(null))); // Identity hashCode of c1.s :1442407170
        Field f2 = c2.getDeclaredField("s");  // getting field s of c2
        f2.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of c2.s :"+ System.identityHashCode(f2.get(null))); // Identity hashCode of c2.s :1442407170
        System.out.println("c1.s == c2.s : " + (f1.get(null) == f2.get(null))); // c1.s == c2.s : true ==> c1.s is the same "instance" as c2.s
        //Make c1 and c2 eligible for GC
        // So, now, there are no references to "abc"
        f1 = null;
        c1 = null;
        f2 = null;
        c2 = null;
       //call GC explicitly. Yes, twice.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        // use the same string literal in main. Just to test that the same literal is being used.
        String s = "abc";
        System.out.println("Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : " + System.identityHashCode(s)); // Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : 1118140819 ==> Oh!!. The IDHashcodes are NOT the same
    }

}
// Our class which will be loaded
class Test {
    static String s = "abc"; // Our little hero!.The string literal. 
}
//Our custom ClassLoader to load the class "Test"
class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    // finalize() is to check if Object is unreachable (and ready for GC)
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("CustomClassLoader finalize called.." + this);
    };

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (!name.equals("Test")) {
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }
        try {
            InputStream in = ClassLoader
                    .getSystemResourceAsStream("Test.class");
            byte[] a = new byte[10000];
            int len = in.read(a);
            in.close();
            return defineClass(name, a, 0, len);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        }
    }
}

O/P :

c1 : class Test
c2 : class Test
c1 == c2 :false
Identity hashCode of c1.s :1442407170 // Value - 1
Identity hashCode of c2.s :1442407170 // Value - 2
c1.s == c2.s : true
CustomClassLoader finalize called..CustomClassLoader@4e25154f // ClassLoader1 GCed
CustomClassLoader finalize called..CustomClassLoader@6d06d69c // ClassLoader2 GCed
Identity hashCode of mainMethod's s : 1118140819 // Value - 3 ..
```

> IdentityHashCodes for (1,2) and 3 are different. So, the string "abc"
>   used in "main" method is not the same string literal "abc" which was
>   added to string constants pool when Test was loaded by 2 different
>   classloaders.

Comment: This sounds good, but I’m trying to nit-pick: can we be sure that if `Test.s` had not been garbage collected, the `s` in `main` would have had the same identityHashCode? Is there any way of detecting that a specific object is garbage collected? (upvote anyway)

Comment: @PJTraill -  *if Test.s had not been garbage collected, the s in main would have had the same identityHashCode?* - check case-1. Since c1 and c2's class loaders are not GCed. The `"abc"` of main and c1 and c2 have same IdentityHashCode

Comment: Can you exclude the hash code depending on the Loader? — that would also produce these results! After all, is `s` in main not created when `TestStringLiteralGC` is loaded?

Comment: @PJTraill - If `s` in `main()` was created before the classloaders get GCed, then it will point to the same "abc". All 3 will have the same IdentityHashCode.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to proof it, is using a [profiler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html). A profiler gives you the ability to see all objects that are in memory of the application.